# Cap for Object instances in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, instance, ram

I was experimenting with object instances, since I wanted to find out if there is a defined maximum amount of object instances for a single Java process. So I simply made an object which calls itself recursivly from the constructor like this:

```
public class A{

    private A a;

    public A(){
        a = new A();
    }
}
```

and a Main class like this:

```
public class random {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
    }
}
```

Which obviously resulted in a Stack Overflow exception. After googling around, I found out, that each Java thread has its own stack. So why not just spawn a new thread before my original one would overflow? So I wrote this:

```
public class A{

    private A a;
    private B b;

    public A(int i, int lim){
        if (i < lim)
            a = new A(i + 1, lim, bufferedWriter);
        else{
            t = new Thread(b = new B(lim));
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

With a runnable like this:

```
public class B implements Runnable {

    private int lim;
    private A a;

    public B(int lim) {
        this.lim = lim;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        a = new A(lim, lim + 2500);
    }
}
```

I suspected it would either throw an exception again or simply crash due to insufficient RAM (which is why I kept my Task Manager open, ready to kill the process). I was surprised to see that after a few minutes, there was no noticeable change in RAM usage and I didn't get any exception. So I checked my run configuration in eclipse, which was also unchanged and set to default values.

To get further insight into the subject I decided to start counting the instances. A first try with a simple "`System.out.println`" wouldn't work, because the thread the system.out-stream runs in would simply overflow. So I decided to write the count into files with one File for each Thread.

My classes now looked like this:

Main:

```
public class random {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            A a = new A(0, 2500, new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(0 + " - " + 2500))));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

A:

```
public class A {

    private A a;
    private Thread t;
    private B b;

    public A(int i, int lim, BufferedWriter bufferedWriter) {
        try {
            bufferedWriter.write(i + "\n");
            bufferedWriter.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (i < lim)
            a = new A(i + 1, lim, bufferedWriter);
        else{
            t = new Thread(b = new B(lim));
            t.start();
            try {
                bufferedWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

B:

```
public class B implements Runnable {

    private int lim;
    private A a

    public B(int lim) {
        this.lim = lim;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            a = new A(lim, lim + 2500, new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(lim + " - " + (lim + 2500)))));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Again, surprisingly my RAM usage was pretty steady. I was more worried about my disk storage, since after about 2 minutes my little programm created over 6500 files (so ~33 files per second), with exactly 2500 numbers in each File (I think... I didn't bother counting) in total counting to 16.260.000. Ofc it wasn't enough to fill my disk, but I stopped it at that point.

Okay if you read all until here, you are either very interested in my little experiment or really want to answer my question... So here it is:

I never set any reference to `null` and any instances I created are indirectly referenced by my main class. So I'd think the garbage collector wouldn't touch my precious instances (right?). How does my RAM not completely fill up? Or how does at least the JVM not reach its allocated RAM limit? If I believe my counter I had over 16 million object instances, not even counting the instances of `B` and it would have created 83.000 more object references *each second* if I had let it keep going.

Also, while we are on the subject: how much RAM would a simple Object use up? I know its obviously related to which and how many variables are referenced and used within the Object, but lets just say a completely empty Object. How much ram would it use?

PS: I know I could probably speed up my programm by starting threads simultaneously in my main class, but it wasn't my (main) intention to use up all my disk space as fast as possible, but to count object instances :)

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I know I wrote a lot, maybe a bit too much. And i know i put a lot of code him, some might think is unnecessary. I understand that. But I am not looking to have a problem solved, but i actually have a question about how something works. If I misunderstood anything about the subject I want people to correct me at the right spot, which is only possible if I show my complete thought process.

Also I wanted to create a friendly atmosphere and invite people to join the discussion by embelleshing my story a little bit, which results in more text, but is also more inviting IMHO.

Comment: Your A object basically needs around 16 bytes or RAM. 16.260.000 objects times 16 bytes is only 260 MB, which is a small amount for today's computers. Your test would be much simpler if you simply filled a very large array with objects. Or if you simply googled for "how much memory does an Object use in Java".

Comment: But thank you for the hint anyways, I'll gladly edit my post if other people see it the same way :)

Comment: @JBNizet Interesting, thanks I didn't think it would be that small! But that still leaves my question, if there is a cap for object instances? Or are we allowed to instanciate as many as we want until the computer crashes?

Comment: There is no cap for object instances. There is a cap for memory. If you create too many instances and the GC is not allowed to collect them, you'll have an OutOfMemoryError evenually, since memory is finite.

Comment: Another issue is that your objects ARE garbage collected. Even if they are in a thread since there is no reference kept to them and they are not used anymore (after writing to the file) they are destroyed

Comment: @JBNizet okay thats what i thought, even though I suspected java would have a built in limit as well. I believe it is possible to limit the JVM memory with specific configurations, right?

Comment: @VeselinDavidov I kind of suspected that, since there was literally no increase in used memory at all. But when I spawn a new thread, I reference the instance of the runnable B (which contains the next A) in the last A of the old thread. Shouldn't that keep the line of references intact?

Comment: The garbage collector sees you are not using it anywhere else and deletes it. Probably checks that the previous A is not referenced etc. Otherwise it will never garbage collect complex objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem with your test is that your objects are still garbage collected. If you create a thread and don't keep reference to it after it finishes its work (write to a file) it is not referenced anymore and java is smart enough to dispose the memory.

So in order to make your example work as expected you need to keep reference to your threads. For example:

```
class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<B> objects=new ArrayList<>();
            while(true){
             objects.add(new B());
            }
        }
}       

class B implements Runnable {           
    @Override
    public void run() {         
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Theoretically there is no limit for object creation. Practically there are limitations depending on heap size. Heap is the memory area allocated by JVM, to store objects. That is why, when your program runs out of memory (heap), you face OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: Ah I'm still struggeling to find the point where I break my chain of references :) since im going "Main->A->A->(2500x)->A->B->A->(2500x)->(...)" and so on. And save each a in the class before and the Bs in the A that calls it. I know the chain must be broken somewhere, since it wouldn't make sense otherwise :P So thank you very much for your answer, it is really helpful for me and my understanding of Java :)

Comment: For example if you have A in your B but it is not referenced anywhere in the code of B after the execution and it is not doing anything on its own then this A is garbage collected as well as B is garbage collected.

Comment: If you have a dog class which has a house and a doghouse which has a dog then these two are coupled but if none of them is referenced outside that relationship and they are not used anywhere they will be garbage collected. Otherwise there won't be any way to dispose complex objects with references. In my example they are stored in a list which is local to the call that creates the threads so they are not garbage collected and fill the memory. I hope I am expaining properly ;) The GC is a bit of a mistery  even if you think you understand it

Comment: yeah, it kinda is :D thanks for the detailed explaination, I think I got it^^